# Change status from 'incomplete' to 'completed'

Tags: html

Can someone help me with PHP coding. How do I change Status from 'incomplete' to 'completed' after the survey was submitted.

For more information, when user click at status 'incomplete', it will redirect to survey.php which require user to answer survey. And after finish and click submit, it will redirect user to previous page and the status will change to 'completed'.

How do I do this?

```html
<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="7" width="630" cellspacing="1">
        <tr>
        <th><font size=2>Modul</font></th>
        <th><font size=2>Status</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr><td><font size=2><center>Survey 1<td><a href="../staff/survey1.php"><center><font size=2>Incomplete</a></td>
        <tr><td><font size=2><center>Survey 2<td><a href="../staff/survey2.php"><center><font size=2>Incomplete</a></td>
        <tr><td><font size=2><center>Survey 3<td><a href="../staff/survey3.php"><center><font size=2>Incomplete</a></td>
        <tr><td><font size=2><center>Survey 4<td><a href="../staff/survey4.php"><center><font size=2>Incomplete</a></td>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This looks like HTML that is output as the result of executing a PHP script. Do you have any of the related server-side code? I would guess that upon completing a survey, its status would need to be updated where said status is persisted (database, etc.). Without seeing any of the server-side code it would be impossible to tell you why that's not happening.

Comment: andrew, thanks for editing. Would you give some guide for my problem? Much appreciated.

Comment: `<font>`? `<center>`? What is this, 1996?

Comment: I just removed the irrelevant tags from your post as there is no php or mysql in the question, please re-word the question, showing what you have attempted so far and errors you are getting

Comment: thanks andrew. And j08691, dont sound like that. I new to PHP. Instead of saying something like that, why dont you give some guidance and soultion. I believe you are professional programmer who instead of saying something not helping, but give some guidance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by sending a get or post parameter when you redirect back to the first website.